# PySpark: Filtering duplicates of a union, keeping only the groupby rows with the maximum value for a specified column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a DataFrame that contains all the rows from two DataFrames, and where there are duplicates we keep only the row with the max value of a column.

For example, if we have two tables with the same schema, like below, we will merge into one table which includes only the rows with the maximum column value (highest score) for the group of rows grouped by another column ("name" in the below example).

```
Table A
+--------------------------+
| name   | source  | score |
+--------+---------+-------+
| Finch  | Acme    | 62    |
| Jones  | Acme    | 30    |
| Lewis  | Acme    | 59    |
| Smith  | Acme    | 98    |
| Starr  | Acme    | 87    |
+--------+---------+-------+


Table B
+--------------------------+
| name   | source  | score |
+--------+---------+-------+
| Bryan  | Beta    | 93    |
| Jones  | Beta    | 75    |
| Lewis  | Beta    | 59    |
| Smith  | Beta    | 64    |
| Starr  | Beta    | 81    |
+--------+---------+-------+


Final Table
+--------------------------+
| name   | source  | score |
+--------+---------+-------+
| Bryan  | Beta    | 93    |
| Finch  | Acme    | 62    |
| Jones  | Beta    | 75    |
| Lewis  | Acme    | 59    |
| Smith  | Acme    | 98    |
| Starr  | Acme    | 87    |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

Here's what seems to work:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = ["name", "source", "score"]

rows1 = [("Smith", "Acme", 98),
         ("Jones", "Acme", 30),
         ("Finch", "Acme", 62),
         ("Lewis", "Acme", 59),
         ("Starr", "Acme", 87)]

rows2 = [("Smith", "Beta", 64),
         ("Jones", "Beta", 75),
         ("Bryan", "Beta", 93),
         ("Lewis", "Beta", 59),
         ("Starr", "Beta", 81)]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rows1, schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows2, schema)

df_union = df1.unionAll(df2)
df_agg = df_union.groupBy("name").agg(F.max("score").alias("score"))
df_final = df_union.join(df_agg, on="score", how="leftsemi").orderBy("name", F.col("score").desc()).dropDuplicates(["name"])
```

The above results in the DataFrame I expect. It seems like a convoluted way to do this, but I don't know as I'm relatively new to Spark. Can this be done in a more efficient, elegant, or "Pythonic" manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions. Partition by `name` and choose the record with the highest `score`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("name").orderBy(desc("score"))

df_union.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(w))\
        .filter(col("rank")==1).drop("rank").show()

+-----+------+-----+                                                            
| name|source|score|
+-----+------+-----+
|Bryan|  Beta|   93|
|Finch|  Acme|   62|
|Jones|  Beta|   75|
|Lewis|  Acme|   59|
|Smith|  Acme|   98|
|Starr|  Acme|   87|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @Cena this works well, very appreciated. Is this likely to be more efficient than what I've proposed above when the table sizes grow large? I will need to do this on tables with ~100M rows so this is a real consideration.

Comment: I think the window functions are more efficient for your case. Especially because you are doing a group by (max) aggregation + a join, which can lower the performance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your answer, except for the last line - you cannot join on score only, but need to join on combination of "name" and "score", and you can choose inner join, which will eliminate the need to remove rows with lower scores for the same name:

```
df_final = (df_union.join(df_agg, on=["name", "score"], how="inner")
                    .orderBy("name")
                    .dropDuplicates(["name"]))
```

Notice that there is no need to order by score, and .dropDuplicates(["name"]) is only needed if you want to avoid displaying two rows for name = Lewis who has the same score in both dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer, Anna. Yes, I want to choose a row at random in the case of a tie such as for Lewis. Also, I'm not clear as to why we get the same result using "name" in the on list as without in my original code (i.e. just joining on score)? Is this a more common idiom in PySpark than window functions? Which is likely to handle it better when the two tables we're unioning have ~100M rows?

Comment: In case of a tie, I don't think you are getting a random row, you get the row of the first dataframe all the time, I believe. Regarding your approach and mine, we get the same results indeed. However, try to change ("Bryan", "Beta", 93) to ("Bryan", "Beta", 64), and remove  orderBy and dropDuplicates, you will see both rows in df_final, which now need to be removed with orderBy and dropDuplicates, while you avoid those extra steps with inner join on name and score, which directly filters out scores that are not max for each name.